# Is it possible to make two tbody align horizontally in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Floating two tbody of a table will make them align horizontally.
It works in Chrome, Firefox, IE9+ except IE6,7.
I've tried trigger hasLayout on the table but no miracle happened.
Someone help me!

(yes, IE6, I'm in China, here's still many people using Windows XP with IE6,7 installed. It's a nightmare for web developer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you use `clear: both`?

This will make ie7 more normally with float!